# gwt getKey method exist?

Tags: java, gwt, localization, internationalization, uibinder

i have file LocalizableResource_XXx.properties .  inside java files, is there such method as .getKey(..)  so that i can use i18n inside java files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want to get by .getKey(...) but I think this piece of code will be helpful to you

```
for (String localeName : LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames()) {
            String displayName = LocaleInfo.getLocaleNativeDisplayName(localeName);
            Label label = new Label();
            label.setText(displayName);
            RootPanel.get("loc").add(label);
        }
```

And survey this link [LocaleInfo.class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.html)

Comment: my question is in java file, how to use the ui:msg key to get i18n from properties files. i know this can be done in xml

Comment: or let me rephrase my question. how to use ui:msg template inside java file rather than uibinder .xml